# BizTalk sending message to Webservice without mapping

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, biztalk-orchestrations

I am new to BizTalk. I got a requirement as below.

Requirement is below:-

1. Source: Oracle (table). I created a generated schema  in BizTalk.
2. Target: Webservice which receives "object array" (Table of source records from BizTalk) as an input.
3. Source and Target systems have same structure. Hence no mapping should be implemented. Logic should be in pipelines or orchestration.

Need info on below two topics:

1. How to incorporate the logic in pipeline or orchestration to map data from source schema to target WS schema.

Answer (score 2):

This question was posed (now deleted) on the other big BizTalk forum.  So I'll share my answer here.

What you're asking is simply not possible.  **It doesn't matter that the source and destination are *logically* the same.**  They are represented by two different schemas in BizTalk.  There is no way around this except by developing the Web Service to accept the WCF Oracle message directly.

Because of that, you must transform from the source to the destination.  Maps are how that is done.  While there are technically other ways, they are harder to write, bug prone and would likely offer a less desirable performance profile.

A ban on Maps is just counter-productive and as a long time BizTalk Developer I could not accept a project with such a requirement.

Comment: I couldn't quite get my head around why a map wasn't possible. I have come across similar attitudes at a few clients, but these tend to be the victims of very badly designed integrations. Shame that a powerful tool like maps can pickup a bad name like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you are asking for to be honest. Your requirement states that no mapping is required, but then you go on to ask how to incorporate mapping in pipeline or orchestrations.

A standard approach to delivering this would be;

1. Setup your input process from Oracle by using "Consume Adapter
   Service" from visual studio's "add generated item". Use the oracle
   binding, setup connection properties for typed polling along with
   your query (see [here](http://tech-findings.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/polling-data-from-sql-using-wcf-sql.html) for an example on MS SQL) change to a
   service contract type (for inbound operations) and you'll get a set
   of schemas representing your dataset, and a binding for your type
   receive port poller.
2. Use "Consume WCF Service" to point to your "sending" web service and
   you'll get the schemas, binding and a helpful orchestration with
   port types add to your project
3. Create a simple map mapping your inbound oracle recordset schema to
   your web service schema - this should be pretty straight forward if
   they are identical, although I suspect you'll have to deal with
   multiple sets of data - depends on your data.
4. Complete by wiring together your orchestration.

I appreciate this is a high level view of what you need to do, but there are plenty of example you can google to get you started. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for your reply. My requirement is that "Step3" you mentioned needs to be done in a Pipeline or Orchestration. My question is how to do this step3 logic in Orchestration or Pipeline. I should not creating a map...

Comment: Well, you *need* to get your input message into your output message. There are lots of ways to do this without a map I suppose. But my question is why wouldn't you ?

Comment: We have a requirement not to use Map as both the source and target structure are same. Can you let me know the best way and the steps to perform.. to get our input message to output message.. regarding performance wise(without a map)..

Comment: They are not the same. I can pretty much bet the bank on that. Look at the schemas that get produced. That's why you need to map/convert/call it what you will.

Comment: At the very least the namespaces of the output messages will be different from the input message, hence you will need to map from one to the other.  If the data structures are the same it will be a very straight forward map from one to the other.